# What are URL codes called?

Tags: url, web

I came across a website with a blog post teaching all how to clear cache for web development purposes. My personal favourite one is to do /? on the end of a web address at the URL bar.

Are there any more little codes like that? if so what are they and where can I find a cheat sheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending `/?` may work for some URLs, but not for all.

It works if the server/site is configured in a way that, for example, `http://example.com/foo` and `http://example.com/foo/?` deliver the same document. But this is not the case for all servers/sites, and the defaults can be changed anyway.

There is no name for this. You just manipulate the canonical URL, hoping to craft a URL that points to the same document, without getting redirected.

Other common variants?

- I’d expect appending `?` would work even more often than `/?` (both, of course, only work if the URL has no query component already).

  ```
  http://example.com/foo
  http://example.com/foo?
  ```
- You’ll also find sites that allow any number of additional slashes where only one slash used to be.

  ```
  http://example.com/foo/bar
  http://example.com/foo////bar
  ```
- Not sure if it affects the cache, but specifying the domain as FQDN, by adding a dot after the TLD, would work for many sites, too.

  ```
  http://example.com/foo
  http://example.com./foo
  ```
- Some sites might not have case-sensitive paths.

  ```
  http://example.com/foo
  http://example.com/fOo
  ```